# Error: Parse error on line 28: Unexpected 'TERMINATOR'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

New with coffee script and I am not sure what's causing this.

```
$ ->
    $('.subscription').hover (event) ->
        $(this).toggleClass("hover")


jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_subscription').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      payment.processCard()
      false

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
      Stripe.createToken(card, payment.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was cause by this line: `Stripe.createToken card, payment.handleStripeResponse`. It is not part of the `card` object.

I made this all a little bit more coffee-ish:

```
$ ->
  $('.subscription').hover (event) ->
    $(this).toggleClass "hover"

jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_subscription').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr 'disabled', no
      payment.processCard()
      false

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken card, payment.handleStripeResponse

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status is 200
      alert response.id 
    else
      alert response.error.message
```

Answer (score 1):

```
processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, payment.handleStripeResponse)  # <-- wrong identation
```